# 'Access attribute not allowed in generic body with external package

Tags: generics, ada

I'm having some issues with generics in Ada. Given the below example, gnatmake results in:

```
g_package.adb:13:33: 'Access attribute not allowed in generic body
g_package.adb:13:33: because access type "t_callback_p" is declared outside generic unit (RM 3.10.2(32))
g_package.adb:13:33: move 'Access to private part, or (Ada 2005) use anonymous access type instead of "t_callback_p"
gnatmake: "g_package.adb" compilation error
```

With the assumption that the external package cannot be changed, is there a way to solve this? I get the reason for the error message in the first place (compiler doesn't know the proper type of the generic package, but it's a bit annoying when the passed function in question doesn't touch any part of the generic..)

g_package.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with external;

package body g_package is
   procedure quix (f : String) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("Does a thing");
   end quix;

   procedure foo (bar : String) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("baz" & bar & Boolean'Image(flag));
      external.procedure_f (quix'Access);
   end foo;
end g_package;
```

g_package.ads

```
generic
   flag : Boolean;
package g_package is
   procedure foo (bar : String);
end g_package;
```

external.ads

```
package external is
   type t_callback_p is access procedure (s : String);
   procedure procedure_f (proc : t_callback_p);
end external;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can (as mentioned in the error message) move the 'Access to the private part of the package spec:

```
private with external;

generic
   flag : Boolean;
package g_package is
   procedure foo (bar : String);

private
   procedure quix (f : String);
   quix_access : constant external.t_callback_p := quix'Access;

end g_package;
```

and the use the constant in the body:

```
external.procedure_f (quix_access);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much. I couldn't quite work out what the error message was talking about, so thanks for explaining it

Comment: Spoke too soon - `instantiation.adb:4:01: instantiation error at g_package.ads:9` `instantiation.adb:4:01: subprogram must not be deeper than access type` any ideas?

Comment: You can't instantiate the generic in the main subprogram, it has to be at the same level as the access type, ie. the library level in this case

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in Ada. If you wish to be non-portable and are using (as it appears) GNAT, you can use the GNAT-specific attribute `'Unrestricted_Access`.